# preventing pause between jquery animations

Tags: jquery-animate, jquery-callback

I have a jquery animation set up, the object fades in and slides down from the top of the screen, and then it should keep moving and fade out.  Right now it fades in, animates down, then pauses, then completes the animation.  I'd really like to get rid of the pause, but I'm not sure how.  I have the animation set up as a call back right now.  You can see it here:

http://jsbin.com/uniyix/12/edit

thanks for any help I can get on this!

Comment: Well the default `easing` of jquery is `swing`. So it is not really a pause but a slow down. So you would need to choose another `easing`.

Comment: t.niese is correct (at least for jQuery animation): http://jsbin.com/uniyix/37/edit.  Alternatively, you could look at CSS3 transitions (http://www.css3.info/preview/css3-transitions/) and keyframe animations to achieve the same result without JS.

Answer (score 0):

Information can be found here at the [Jquery animate() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). More specifically, the **easing** parameter.

There are two kinds of easing: one is *swing* (which is default and features an increase of velocity at the beginning of the animation as well as a slow down at the end, which can look like a "pause" if you have multiple animations set) and the other one is *linear*.

Linear has no slowdown as the speed is constant throughout. The easing parameter can be defined right after the speed parameter.

So this:

```
$('#example').animate({
  'marginLeft' : "+=30",
  }, 3000, function() {
});
```

Would become this:

```
$('#example').animate({
    'marginLeft' : "+=30",
  }, 3000, "linear", function() {
});
```

This should get rid of the pause as the element will be in a constant velocity throughout the entire animation.